# Jenkins - Shows file.AccessDeniedException: for custom workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed Jenkins on Ubuntu 16.04 and created one project using custom work space. When I run project, it shows me following exception related to access.

I have tried following solutions, but it's not working.

sudo chmod -R 777 DevQA/

sudo chown -R jenkins DevQA/

Can anyone please help me resolving this issue.

Exception

```
Building in workspace /root/DevQA/ERBatch 
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /root/DevQA 
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84) 
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) 
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) 
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.checkAccess(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:308) 
at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:746) 
at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:3273)
```

Answer (score 1):

Parent directory (`/root`) needs to have at least `rx` for non-owner to list its content and `w` to make changes there, regardless of subdirectory permissions.

However why not create dedicated directory eg. in `/opt` and use that?